# How to see if an NPM package was installed from NPM or from another source

Tags: npm, npm-package

I am trying to help someone that is having the same problem with an npm package, and I am pretty sure that it had to do with where I installed it from. Is there a way I can see where the package was installed? It would either be installed from the npm repository or straight from the GitHub repository, but I can't remember which one I used.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this by looking in the `package-lock.json` file.

1. Find the package name under the `dependencies` or `devDependencies`
2. Copy the package name
3. Search for it in the file (`CTRL`+`F` is most likely the shortcut to open the find tool)
4. Look under the one that says `node_modules/package-name`
5. You should see a URL in the `resolved` property. This is the install source.

In my case the source was `registry.npmjs.org` which means I installed the one from npms repository, not straight from GitHub.